# Replace images that does not exist in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After series of search on stackoverflow, i got these two working htaccess codes, however, i'm confused which one is better.

Actually both works fine but is there any difference in performance or speed?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
ErrorDocument 404 "/no_profile_picture.png"
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* /no_profile_picture.png [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both directives will serve the core purpose of showing `/no_profile_picture.png` when an image with `jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico` extensions is not found inside your site root. However there is a subtle difference.

```sh
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
ErrorDocument 404 "/no_profile_picture.png"
</FilesMatch>
```

This directive will also return `404 (Http NotFound)` status to browser/client but the other block will still return `200 (Http OK)` status back to clients. So I suggest going with `FilesMatch` block for correctly showing desired non-found image and returning `404` to clients.